# The series of functions $C^1$-converges without normal convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $I=[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb R$.

## Definition

A series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ of functions on $I$ is called convergent [normally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) on $I$ if the series of supreme norms $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sup_{x\in I}\lvert f_n(x)\rvert$ converge.

## Questions

Does there exist a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ of smooth functions on $I$ such that both the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert f_n\rvert$ and the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert f_n'\rvert$ converge uniformly but the series $\sum_nf_n$ does not converge normally? In addition, what if we suppose that the derivatives $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert f_n^{(r)}\rvert$ converge uniformly for all $r\in\mathbb N$?

## Background

It is known that uniform convergence does not imply normal convergence, even if the functions are nonnegative. A typical example in textbooks is the series of functions
\[
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac x{(x^2+n^2)\ln n}
\]
on $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$. My first question is that whether it is possible to find examples such that the domain is compact, say $I$? I find it not difficult because we can pose a sequence of nonnegative smooth functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on $I$ such that $\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}\supp f_i\cap\supp f_j=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$. Then it is possible to arrange the sequence $(f_n)$ such that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined by $a_n:=\sup_{x\in I}f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ but the series $\sum_n a_n$ diverges. However, I noticed that this kind of examples might not work if we impose a control on the derivative. Therefore I wonder what if we impose that the derivative converges also uniformly?